# External jars in scala

Tags: scala, scala-ide, scala-2.11

I want to start the app in console, but can't do this. In Scala IDE I add external jars and start the app, but `scala -cp path/to/jars app.scala` is not working. How to execute it?

Comment: You need to add every jar to the classpath, not just directory, where they are. Check out here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html Also `path/to/jars/*` may work. Note, that these are only external jars. The directory with the classes you are are running needs to be added too.

Comment: My .scala also have to be in classpath or compiled .class ?